# Вызов сервлета из jsp

Tags: servlet, java, jsp

```
<%

    request.setAttribute("path", "statement");
    request.setAttribute("name", "test.zip");
//response.sendRedirect("/Download");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/download").forward(request, response);
%>
```

Подскажите, как мне передать данные с jsp сервлету. 
Я пытаюсь скачать файл с сервлета, сам сервлет проверял, работает, если подставить данные вручную,

Код сервлета:

```
public class Download extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String filePath = request.getParameter("path");
        String fileName = request.getParameter("name");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        ServletOutputStream out=response.getOutputStream();
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName);
        File f = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"),filePath+"/"+fileName);
        long len = f.length();
        response.addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(len));
        response.setContentType("application/download");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        int i;
        while((i=fileInputStream.read())!=-1){
            out.write(i);
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
        out.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

}
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jsp добавить форму с вызовом метода сервлета, что-то вроде:

```
<form method="get" action="Download">
    <input name="filePath"/>
    <input name="fileName"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Чтобы Dispatcher знал, какой сервлет ответит на `action="Download"`, нужно добавить или аннотацию к сервлету вида: `@WebServlet("/Download")`, или прописать связь в ХМЛ:

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>my_servlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>app.servlets.my_servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>my_servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/Download</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```